# Django passing arguments through save methods (models)

Tags: python, django, django-models, parameter-passing

i have models in django like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    type = (choices)

class Bill(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)

class Detail(models.Model):
    total = models.MoneyField() # i used currency package
    bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill)
```

Detail class contains sales detail for the Bill, i already made a transaction to save bill and details at the same time in Bill.save() method but i want to pass Client.type from Bill.save() to Detail.Save(), i want something like that

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): #this is Bill save method
    client = self.Client
    transaction.atomic:
        super(Bill, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        for detail in self.details
            detail.save(client)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs): #this is Detail save method
    self.pricing(client)
    super(Detail, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def pricing(self, client):
    if client.type = 'value1':
        self.total = self.total - (self.total*5/100)
    elif client.type = 'value2':
        self.total = self.total - (self.total*7/100)
    else:
        self.total = self.total - (self.total*10/100)
```

i don't know how passing arguments works on python and Django, what is the cleanest solution to solve this problem? in short i want the bill.save method to pick the client.type value and passe it through detail.save to calculate total with cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the parameter in kwargs in save method try the following code to pass the client variable (`detail.save(client=client)`) in another save method and access this variable by using `client = kwargs.get('client')`

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): #this is Bill save method
    client = self.Client
    transaction.atomic:
        super(Bill, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        for detail in self.details
            detail.save(client=client)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs): #this is Detail save method
    client = kwargs.get('client')
    self.pricing(client)
    super(Detail, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

May be this helps you..

Comment: Thanks you, i'll try your solution tonight if it works (this project is in my home computer)

Comment: your solution seem to work when i create a new record, but when a try to update it i receive this error message: got an unexpected keyword argument 'client'

Comment: When you update the entry pass the client variable in it `.save(client=client)`

Comment: i was thinking about another solution, if can i retrieve client directly from detail save method something like `client = self.bill.client`  , but i don't how to do that and if that solution will not give us (N+1) queries problem

Comment: i finally resolved the problem, i just used `client = self.bill.client` in detail save method and send it to pricing method, it's just pylint deceived me with false errors, anyway thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can simple use self property:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): #this is Detail save method
    self.pricing(self.bill.client)
    #           ^^^^^^^^^^^
    super(Detail, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thank you i used your suggestion with @nikhil solution, i also noticed that pylint generate lot of false errors which confused me lot these days